# Receive push notification only when new mail get in Inbox in Gmail

Tags: push-notification, google-api, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-dotnet-client

I am successfully receiving push notifications with service account for a gmail user (impersonate) following [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push).

But when calling `watch` I would like to be notified only when new messages arrive, not when any change happens. (For example: message read, message deleted ...)

I try filtering by `INBOX` and `UNREAD`, but I get notification even when messages is marked as read.

My code:

```
this._service.Users.Watch(new WatchRequest
{
    TopicName = "projects/my-project-id/topics/gmail",
    LabelFilterAction = "include",
    //LabelIds = new [] { "UNREAD" }
    LabelIds = new[] { "INBOX" }
}, "me").Execute();
```

Is it possible to receive notification only when new message arrives?

And here is code for subscribing:

```
var projectId = "my-project-id";
var topicId = "gmail";
var subscriptionId = "unread-gmail";

TopicName topicName = new TopicName(projectId, topicId);
SubscriptionName subscriptionName = new SubscriptionName(projectId, subscriptionId);
PublisherClient publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName);
SubscriberClient subscriber = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);
await subscriber.StartAsync((msg, cancellationToken) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message {msg.MessageId} published at {msg.PublishTime.ToDateTime()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Text: '{msg.Data.ToStringUtf8()}'");
    return Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack);
});
```

Comment: Hi Makla, did you manage to only be notified when new emails come in? I'm also trying to achieve this but didn't find anything useful so far...

Comment: @Valip No, I think it is not possible, but I am not sure.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep investigating and let you know if there is any way to make this work.

Comment: @Makla : Let me know if you found any solution for above problem. I am looking for similar solution to get particular event only from pub-sub.